# Using the Table Type input Parameter in the 'IN' clause

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the table type as my input parameter in my stored procedure and I am passing in a list of comma separated Catalog Ids from my C# application.

But there is also an option on the web page where users can select 'All Catalog Ids' on the multi-select Catalog drop down.

What is the best 'short hand' way to write the query? Like, If I have a varchar variable as my input variable, then I would have written

```
SELECT [FIELD1], [FIELD2] FROM CATALOG WHERE (**@VarcharVariable is NULL** or CatalogName = @VarcharVariable ) for example.
```

But I am struggling to get that kind of 'short hand' notation on the WHERE clause, with this table type input parameter, as Table type parameter cannot be NULL.

I don't want to write a bunch of IF clauses, as I have 4 input parameters of list type that I am sending to this proc and Catalog ID is just one of them. I just want to JOIN the values in these input parameters with my base tables and send the output with a concise single query. Unfortunately any of these 4 table type input parameters can have 'All' as its value. If ALL, I just have to get everything of that entity.

I want to join these input parameters with my base tables ONLY if they have valid ids in the table and does not have 'All' equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used a bit variable. Here IDList is a user-defined type that I have created. If we see the WHERE condition below, I used the OR condition to keep it to one concise query but yet join bunch of base tables based on these list type (comma delimited string of IDs) of input parameters.

When I have to pass ALL from my c# app, I literally null the datatable input parameter out, so that these bit variables will have a value of 0 and the query pulls in all records for that entity..

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc
(
     @CatelogIDs IDList READONLY,
     @TaskIDs IDList READONLY,
     @SomeOtherIDs IDList READONLY

)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @bCatIDs bit=0
        DECLARE @bTaskIDs bit=0
        DECLARE @bSomeOtherIDs  bit=0

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CatelogIDs) 
        BEGIN
            SET @bCatIDs =1
        END
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TaskIDs) 
        BEGIN
            SET @bTaskIDs =1
        END
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SomeOtherIDs) 
        BEGIN
            SET @bSomeOtherIDs =1
        END

        SELECT col1, col2,col3
                
                FROM [dbo].[MainTable] r
                JOIN [dbo].Catalogs c ON c.ID = r.CatalogID
                JOIN [dbo].[Tasks] t ON t.ID = r.TaskId
                JOIN [dbo].[SomeotherTable] s ON s.ID = r.SomeotherID
                WHERE (@bCatIDs = 0 OR r.CatalogID in (SELECT IDs FROM @CatelogIDs))AND
                      (@bTaskIDs = 0 OR r.TaskID in (SELECT IDs FROM @TaskIDs)) AND
                      (@bSomeOtherIDs = 0 OR r.SomeotherID in (SELECT IDs FROM @bSomeOtherIDs))
```